# Show Home Link In wp_nav_menu but only on primary menu

Tags: menus

This function adds a home link into my nav menu, but it is added to 3 other menus I am using as well. I don't quite understand where to add code to only display in my primary nav.

```
function my_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'my_page_menu_args' );
```

Comment: Couldn't find an answer so I am now hiding the other home links with css.

Comment: What function you use to display menus? I guess `wp_page_menu` right?

Comment: Yep the following code `<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'menu-header', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
function my_page_menu_args( $args ) {
    if($args['theme_location'] === 'primary')
        $args['show_home'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'wp_page_menu_args', 'my_page_menu_args' );
```

The $args array also contains the theme location, so you can filter on that.